# Misplaced alignement tab character &

Tags: latex, bibtex

I'm trying to cite a certain book in my article. But somehow, it messes up processing the "&" symbol. Although I tried using "\&" instead of "&", it keeps giving me the same error. The bibtex entry is given below.

```
@book{dasgupta11,
  title={The Science of Drinking: How Alcohol Affects Your Body and Mind},
  author={Dasgupta, A.},
  year={2011},
  publisher={Rowman \& Littlefield Publishers},
}
```

The specific error message I get from this is:

> Misplaced alignment tab character &. Rowman &Littlefield Publishers ...lisher{}{Rowman & Littlefield Publishers}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to find the answer after searching for a little longer. I deleted all the additional files in the folder containing the .tex. These include the .blg, .bbl, .log, .aux and .gz files. Aftert this, I recompiled, and everything seems to be working fine now.

Comment: Like the old tip *turn it off and on* just cleaning up the cache/helper files solved it. +1